# Three.js iPad performance

Tags: ipad, three.js

before I totally give up on this idea I wanted to check with the three.js community to make sure that I'm not doing something wrong?

Essentially I have taken Mr doobs canvas geometry cube example http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_cube.html and applied an image to the cube faces.  When testing on the iPad I have frame a frame speed of 1fps (as opposed to 60fps with the original example).  The image also looks really broken up on rotation.

Are there any tricks on getting this to work well on the iPad?  I'm aware that WebGL isn't supported but I thought the canvas renderer would perform better than it is?

Code below

Many thanks

```
function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            var info = document.createElement( 'div' );
            info.style.position = 'absolute';
            info.style.top = '10px';
            info.style.width = '100%';
            info.style.textAlign = 'center';
            info.innerHTML = 'Drag to spin the cube';
            container.appendChild( info );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.y = 150;
            camera.position.z = 500;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            // Cube

            var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            loader.load( 'test-texture.png', function ( texture ) {
                var materials = [];
                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, overdraw: 0.5 } );
                material.transparent = true;
                for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i ++ ) {
                 materials.push( material );
                }
                // then the cube definitions
                cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 200, 200, 200,4,4,4), new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
                cube.position.y = 150;
                scene.add( cube );

                animate();   
            });

            // Plane

            var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 200, 200 );
            geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( - Math.PI / 2 ) );

            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xe0e0e0, overdraw: 0.5 } );

            plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( plane );

            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor( 0xf0f0f0 );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
            container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to wait for iOS8 which should bring WebGL support.